# Is google place API free?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to use **google place API** in a web application, I just wanted to confirm that API is free or not?
If it is Paid feature then what are the charges?

Comment: Can't you look up the documentation before opening a question here?

Comment: I had read the documentation, but I m not able to get any proper detail about pricing.

Comment: Well I am sorry then because searching for "google maps api pricing" in a search engine brings me to it immediately.

Answer (score 8):

You may view the pricing of each API [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use).

Places API is not free, however, once you set up your billing account, you will be entitled for a one time $300 free credit(usable for Google Cloud Platform products) and a monthly recurring $200 free credit(exclusive for Google Maps Platform products), after consuming the credits, you will receive an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT and will not be billed.

If you wish to not receive an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error when credits are exhausted, you may upgrade your billing account and will be billed accordingly for the usage after the credits.

Answer (score 1):

For each API you need to enable billing but the first $200 of each month is free. Check out the pricing structure for specific API and functionality to better understand how much $200 will get you (based on Oct'19 price structure).
Source: [Google cloud pricing](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a billing account if you want to use this API.

**From [the documentation:](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing)**

Reminder: To use the Places API, you must include an API key with all API requests and you must enable billing on each of your projects.

You don't have to pay for this API because the payment method are pay as you go but you will need to restrict your requests quota so you wont get charged.