# Google Sheet Script - Find nearby cities within 25 mile radius

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is a formula that I used to get the mile radius distance between the origin and destination.

```
 function FlyingMeters(origin,destination) {
    var geoOrigin = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(origin);
    var geoDestination = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(destination);
    return haversine({lat:geoOrigin.results[0].geometry.location.lat,lng:geoOrigin.results[0].geometry.location.lng},
                    {lat:geoDestination.results[0].geometry.location.lat,lng:geoDestination.results[0].geometry.location.lng});
  }

function haversine(latLng1, latLng2) {
  var radius = 6371000;
  var dLat = (latLng2.lat-latLng1.lat) * Math.PI/180;
  var dLng = (latLng2.lng-latLng1.lng) * Math.PI/180;
  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
          Math.cos(latLng1.lat * Math.PI/180) * Math.cos(latLng2.lat * Math.PI/180) *
          Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  var d = radius * c;
  return d;
}

function FlyingMiles(origin,destination) {
  return FlyingMeters(origin,destination)/1609.34;
}
```

Is there a way get the surrounding cities within 25 mile radius of a City? Do I need to register for a google API? I'm having trouble formulating the radius. Assuming I need a list of cities in a database / sheet, that list is readily available with each having long and lat values.

Comment: Does "Nearby Search" https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby work for you?

Comment: @barrycarter I'm not sure if I'm doing this right but I tried creating a new project to enable the API but it seems like I need to pay in order to enable it. Is there a way to make this free?

Comment: There's no "free usage tier" like they have for other APIs? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000869/is-google-place-api-free